# aligning radio button text when using transform and scale to change radiobutton size

Tags: css

To make the ( ) bigger on my radio buttons, I'm using this css which I found here on SO a while back (sorry, don't have the reference handy):

```
     input[type=radio]
{
    /* Double-sized */
    -ms-transform: scale(2); /* IE */
    -moz-transform: scale(2); /* FF */
    -webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: scale(2); /* Opera */
    padding: 1em;
    height: 2em; 
}
```

But the ( ) part of the radio button is obscuring part of the first letter of the text:

```
    ( )ushrooms
    ( )nchovies
    ( )xtra Cheese
    ( )reen Peppers
    ( )rtichokes
```

How to create some space between the button portion and the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some right margin: `margin-right: 1em;`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to inspect the element and see what margin is applied by the browser to the input[type="radio"] with the default user agent CSS stylesheet.

Usually the default is `margin: 3px 3px 0px 5px;` but it differs between browsers.

Change it to  `margin: 3px 10px 0px 5px;` since you need to increase the right margin on the right side of the input or to whatever value you believe it's suitable. You can use also percentages in case you are building a responsive or fluid layout.

Each value correspond to top, right, bottom, left.

**EXAMPLE:** margin: 3px 10px 0px 5px; (top, right, bottom, left)

http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/bczrs8g2/1/

This is the shorthand property for margin.